# AWK does not sum decimals

Tags: command-line, awk

I have a file, `z`:

```
.57
.57
.57
.57
```

I type: `awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}' z` and I get `0`.

I have a file, `zz`:

```
1
2
3
4
```

I type: `awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}' zz` and I get `10`.

Why those sums are different?

Comment: What implementation of awk is being used here (`gawk`? `mawk`?). Is your locale one in which the decimal separator is something other than `.`? What happens if you type `LC_NUMERIC=C awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}' z` ?

Comment: @steeldriver thank you, you are right, it is a locale problem, I have already fixed